# Camera Automation Testing In Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-espresso

I am doing automation testing using `Espresso` but I struggle in Camera Capture... I have written code for camera that it will open, but it is not able to click. What I need is to click in automatically if it is possible.

Please give me any suggestions. Below is my code:

```
onView(withId(R.id.photo)).perform(click());
```

Comment: Is the Activity that is capturing images in the same application as the one being tested?

Comment: yes i have testing this as same application

Answer (score 0):

Things get tricky with Espresso when you are working with tests that include multiple `Activities`. I prefer to use `UIAutomator` for such parts of the test.

With `UIAutomator`, you can do something like:

```
UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())
        .findObject(new UiSelector()
                .resourceId("com.example.package:id/photo")).click();
```

Remember that your `IdlingResources` won't have any effect on `UIAutomator`, so you might need to add extra delays to wait for that `Activity` to be created and initialized before it is clicked on.

Here is how to setup `UIAutomator`: [UIAutomator Testing | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing.html)

Comment: android.support.test.uiautomator.UiObjectNotFoundException: UiSelector[RESOURCE_ID=photo]
 i have get this type of exception

Comment: i want to know y u mentioned photo in string..?

Comment: Thank u so much i is working... but i need to capture camera

Comment: Oh, I am sorry, I wrote the resource ID wrongly. It needs to be mentioned in this specific format as mentioned.

Comment: ya instead  i have put camera package it is open but i need to capture image if it is possible

Comment: if it is possible please give me suggestion

Comment: If you query mentioned in the question is resolved, you may mark the answer as accepted. You may ask a separate question for other queries, that would help you get more helpful answers.

Comment: thank u for ur suggestion i have get .. i m able to capture camera ... thank u for ur suggestion